# AG-GRID: Is there a way to have expand/collapse functionality on a row and show custom content in the expanded area?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We need to have the ability to expand/collapse individual rows and when expanded show custom (angular) components in the area below the row, which will receive as input some of the data of the expanded row.

The closest thing we found is the Master/Detail feature of the enterprise version, but we don't want to display a nested table within, we want to have custom content.

similar to this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcxRW.png)

Comment: Please provide sample of your code and what've you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Master-details` feature of [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid).

The feature is available with enterprise license.

Reference: [Example - Custom Detail Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#example-custom-detail-cell-renderer-with-a-form)

Comment: amazing! thank you @Paritosh . Can't believe I missed that...

Comment: Is there any other solution for community ag-grid library?

Answer (score 0):

I based my tree grid implementation off of this:
`https://riddheshganatra.medium.com/tree-data-with-ag-grid-community-94ba1dfb40eb`
with the associated code repo here:
`https://github.com/riddheshganatra/ag-grid-tree`
and some work I did to clarify it for readability (in my mind at least), as well as some optimization (recursive search to lookup-table) and making things into a proper class structure to align more with ag-grid documentation examples.

```
https://github.com/nmz787/ag-grid-tree
```

Comment: Link-only answers are prone to rotting. Could you include the relevant code in this answer?